# What JS library would you use to create an interactive custom map

Tags: javascript, angular, interactive, warehouse

I am building an interactive map view of a local area that shows multiple warehouses.

What I would like to know is, what are JS libraries or technologies I can use to achieve:

- Select a building
- View warehouse information such as (Size, Owner etc..)
- Update warehouse information (Rent etc..)
- Be able to draw more warehouses or select a sub area inside a warehouse to rent.

I will be using Angular for frontend and Java Cuba Platform backend.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have used the [Plotly JavaScript Open Source Graphing Library](https://plotly.com/javascript/) and it is very amazing with graphs and maps.
Start from [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/)

Answer (score -1):

- Google Maps: easy, well-documented support
- ArcGIS: advanced, layers of secondary data